# How can I fetch MySQL datas in bootstrap multiselect?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I created an admin panel for MySQL database, and when I click on the edit button, I want to print all of the datas in Bootstrap multi select. If I didn't use Bootstrap multi select, just the normal multi select, it's working. How can I do this?

This is how it looks like (in the button, it show the current datas, but when I open, it didn't showin the select menu):

[image]

### index.php

```
<select name="classification[]" id="classification" multiple="multiple">
   <?php 
      while($row = $classificationResult -> fetch_array()) {
   ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $row['classification_id'];?>"><?php echo $row['name'];?></option>
   <?php
      }
   ?>
</select>

<script>
   // If I didn't add the multi select jquery, it's working
   $('#classification').multiselect({
        nonSelectedText: 'Select Framework',
        maxHeight : 400,
        includeSelectAllOption : false,
        enableFiltering : false,
        buttonWidth : '100%',
        dropRight : true
    });

        $(document).on('click', '.edit_data', function(){
            $("#classification option").prop("selected", false);
            var data_id = $(this).attr("id");  
            $.ajax({  
                url:"fetchRole.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:{'data_id':data_id},  
                dataType:"json",  
                success:function(data){  
                    $.each(data.classifications, function(i, e) {
                        $("#classification option[value='" + e + "']").prop("selected", true);
                    });
                    $('#data_id').val(data.id);  
                    $('#insert').val("Edit");  
                    $('#add_data_Modal').modal('show');  
                }  
            });  
        });  
</script>
```

### fetchRole.php

```
$query2 = $conn -> prepare("SELECT classification.classification_id AS class_id
            FROM classification
            LEFT JOIN role_classification ON classification.classification_id = role_classification.classification_id
            WHERE role_classification.role_id = ?");
        $query2 -> bind_param('i', $role['id']);
        $query2 -> execute();
        $result2 = $query2 -> get_result();
        $query2 -> close();

        while ($classification = $result2 -> fetch_assoc()) {
            $classificationIdList[] = $classification["class_id"];
        }



        $return = array_merge($role, ["classifications" => $classificationIdList]);

    echo json_encode($return);
```

Comment: Can you include the code that shows "If I didn't use Bootstrap multi select, just the normal multi select, it's working"?  Also, what is the result of the bootstrap attempt above? What _is_ happening? Are you getting errors? Have you checked your Javascript console?

Comment: The code are the same, but I didn't use the bootstrap multi select in the javascript and it prints the current classifications in the console.

Comment: Which would make it _not_ the same. If we can see what you did that got your results that you wanted, it will be easier to show you how to modify that to get similar results with bootstrap.

Comment: I edited and I attached a picture to show how it looks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to refresh the multiselect after you set new selected options using `.prop("selected", true)`.

```
$.each(data.classifications, function(i, e) {
    $("#classification option[value='" + e + "']").prop("selected", true);
});

$('#classification').multiselect('refresh');
```

Description of the `refresh` method:

> This method is used to refresh the checked checkboxes based on the
>   currently selected options within the select.

You can see the full list of available methods [HERE](http://davidstutz.de/bootstrap-multiselect/#methods).